# How to find all the services attached to a default security group in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, vpc

I am willing to make some changes to the rules of the default security groups in Production Environment of an AWS account to be compliant to some config rules. To know the impact after the changes made and then testing needs to be done on those parts. To reduce the efforts for testing, it will be better to know of all the services that can take a hit.

Thus, I need to find which are the different Amazon Web Services attached to the default security group in my custom VPC. Is there any AWS CLI command or any way from the AWS Console that I can find out all the different services (like EC2, RDS, etc.) attached to the default security group.

The Network interfaces (ENI) in EC2 Console only shows if an EC2 instance is attached. How to check if the security group is attached to other services?

Please let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: You can try this link to find resources attached to your security group https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-find-security-group-resources/

Comment: I think you should use firewall manager service. You can use an audit security group policy to check the existing rules that are in use in your organization's security groups. You can scope the policy to audit all accounts, specific accounts, or resources tagged within your organization. Firewall Manager automatically detects new accounts and resources and audits them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution, you can list all Security groups in AWS cli with your target information then run again its output to list vpcinfo for all the VPC.

here in action!!

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups |grep 'GroupName\|VpcId\|GroupId' #listing all SG with info groupName/ID,vpcID.
```

[output of listing all SG info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQpxr.png)
now can run below one liner script to fetch all VPC info

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups |grep 'GroupName\|VpcId\|GroupId' > list_sg_info.txt ; cat list_sg_info.txt|grep -i vpcid |sort -u |awk '{print $NF}'|tr '\"' ' '|while read vpcinfo; do  aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids $vpcinfo|nl ; done
```